# Layout on the bottom of Relative layout overlays the views under it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

My screen consists of four main views:

1)admob view

2)top layout

3)ScrollView in the center, which is filled programmatically

4)bottom view. EditView height is expandable in there.

Problem is that bottom view overlays content of scrollView.
That is to say scrollView does not end on the beginning of bottom layout.

The site prohibit me to send much code, so I send short xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<include layout="@layout/adview"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/top"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textChatSubjectTitle"
                android:text='Subject'
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageChatImageTitle"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollChat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/linearChat"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
            >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonClip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            />


    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChatSend"
            android:text='send'
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  I gave your bottom panel an id, and then added a android:layout_above tag to your ScrollView.  I also cleaned things up based on lint warnings I was getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/adview" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textChatSubjectTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Subject"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageChatImageTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonClip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChatSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="send"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGray"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! But I could not understand what you did: I also cleaned things up based on lint warnings I was getting: